# Using dark mode as notification on iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, remote-control, dark-mode

I’m wondering if its possible to use dark mode on Mac or iOS as a kind of notification. Like, connect it to an external trigger / api and activate / deactivate it quickly whenever an event happens.

At least in macOS, its possible to control dark mode remotely.

Comment: Have you tried using the shortcuts app?